# Using multiple Google Translator HTML Widgets not working.

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I need two different Google Translate Widgets for a website.

The problem is that only one instance is initializing.

```
<header>
  <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit1() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit1">
  </script>
</header>

<footer>
  <div id="google_translate_element_bottom"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit2() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        includedLanguages: 'fr, de',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
      }, 'google_translate_element_bottom');
    }
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2">
  </script>
</footer>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmyb1qxn/

I also cannot find an API documentation.

Comment: `I also cannot find an API documentation` - you mean this [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) (I binged it /irony)